# Merge HTML element attributes with node

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have this HTML `string` in node:

```
<a data-style="width:32px" id="heilo-wrld" style="height:64px">
    Hello world
</a>
```

The code has `data-style` and `style` attributes I would like to merge in one `style` attribute like this:

```
<a id="heilo-wrld" style="width:32px; height:64px;">
    Hello world
</a>
```

I could also have complex HTML blocks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper" data-style="background-color: red;">
    <a data-style="width:32px" id="heilo-wrld" style="height:64px">
        Hello world
    </a>
</div>
```

To get this result:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-color: red;">
    <a id="heilo-wrld" style="width:32px; height:64px;">
        Hello world
    </a>
</div>
```

I found some plug-in but it does not do this specific job:

- [sanitize-html](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html)
- [htmltidy](https://github.com/vavere/htmltidy)

Does exists some smart way to do that?

Comment: Why do you need to remove the `data-*` attribute from  `html`?

Comment: because I need it only as rendered HTML as preview, there is also a situation where I'll copy the html in clipboard without `data-style` properties (used just for render purposes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom), you could define a `mergeStyles` function like this:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');

function mergeStyles(html, callback) {
  return jsdom.env(html, function(errs, window) {
    const { document } = window;

    Array.from(
      document.querySelectorAll('[data-style]')
    ).forEach(function(el) {
      const styles = [];

      Array.from(el.attributes).forEach(function(attr) {
        if (attr.name !== 'style' && attr.name !== 'data-style') {
          return;
        }

        styles.push(attr.value);

        el.removeAttributeNode(attr);
      });

      if (!styles.length) {
        return;
      }

      el.setAttribute('style', styles.join(';'));
    });

    const result = document.body.innerHTML;

    return callback(null, result);
  });
}
```

Then call it like:

```
const input = `
    <div class="wrapper" data-style="background-color: red;">
        <a data-style="width:32px" id="heilo-wrld" style="height:64px">
            Hello world
        </a>
    </div>
`;

mergeStyles(input, function(err, result) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  // `result` should contain the HTML with the styles merged.
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: This was what I needed for, thank you and happy new year!